# How to determine the in-degree and out-degree of a node from a graph?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, neighbours, digraphs

Whenever I apply `H.neighbors()`, to any node from my graph it shows none.

```
import networkx as nx
graph={'A': ['B', 'C'],
       'B': ['C', 'D'],
       'C': ['D','A'],
       'D': ['C'],
       'E': ['F'],
       'F': ['C']}
G = nx.Graph(graph)
H = G.to_directed(graph)
H = nx.DiGraph(graph)
all_adjacent_cells = ['All Adjacent Cells']
backward_cells = ['All Input Cells']
forward_cells = ['All Output Cells']
print(all_adjacent_cells.append(G.neighbors('B')))
print((backward_cells.append(H.neighbors('B'))))
```

Whenever I apply `H.neighbors('B')`, put any node from my graph it shows
none. But the output should be

```
backward_cells = 2
forward_cells = 1
```

How can i get the numbers of neighbor input connected net and output
connected net?

Answer (score 2):

The `None` that your code is printing out is not the neighbors of `'B'`.

It comes from `print(all_adjacent_cells.append(G.neighbors('B')))`.  What does this command do?  `G.neighbors('B')` is a specific type of object (at the moment it's not important what that type is).  It takes that object and appends it to `all_adjacent_cells`, which is a list, that happens to have the string `'All Adjacent Cells'` as its first element (aside, I generally don't think it's a good idea to have lists where some elements mean something completely different from the other elements).

Now what is the returned value of the function `append`?  If I set `x = L.append(5)`, that assignment doesn't really mean what you think it means.  `L.append(5)` modifies `L`.  It appends `5` to it.  `L` itself is modified.  So what is `x`?  It's whatever `append` returns, which is not the same thing as what `append` modifies.  More precisely, `append` returns `None`.  And that returned value is what your print statement is printing.

Try this:

```
L=[1,2,3]
x = L.append(4)
print(L)
> [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(x)
> None
```

Now how to do what you want to do?  The object `G.neighbors('B')` is a type of iterator.  For your purposes, I recommend converting it into a list `list(G.neighbors('B'))`  This is something you can print, and it will give the result you want

```
print(list(G.neighbors('B')))
> ['A', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i actually needed the numbers of input connected net of 'B' like for this graph for 'B' the input connected net is 'C' and 'D'                                                                          'B': ['C', 'D'], as you can see in this line .So for B they will give me 2 as output as there are two elements over there

Comment: `H.successors('B')` gives the nodes that `B` links to (`H.neighbors('B')` also gives this).  `H.predecessors('B')` gives the nodes that link to `B`.